# Replace the middle of a string with only 3 chars

Tags: c#, regex, replace

What can I use to replace the middle char in a string like this: `000` becomes `010`.

Do I have to do it with Regex, if yes, can i have the pattern? Or just with the `String.Replace` method?

Info: There are always numbers in the string.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough details about what you'd want to do. Please provide other input / output combinations - what would you want "123" to become, for example?

Comment: A little more input/output will help us.

Answer (score 3):

There is no clear logic behind the replace procedure, looking on the question, but *assuming* that you at some point know which symbol should appear in the middle,

can create an *extension* method, say like this

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string ReplaceMiddle(this string value, char charToPutIn)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(value);
        builder[value.Length/2] = charToPutIn;
        return builder.ToString();
    }

}
```

and after use this like this:

```
"hello".ReplaceMiddle('5')
```

which will produce result like:

```
"he5lo"
```

as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
 string s = "111000111";
 string pattern = "000";
 string replacement = "010";
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 string result = rgx.Replace(s, replacement);
 lbloriginal.Text = s;
 lblnew.Text = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a 3 character string:

```
String number = "123";
String res = number[0] + "5" + number[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing characters or substrings *by index* is a bit awkward to do. It would boil down to

```
string newString = str.Substring(0,1) + newChar + str.Substring(2);
```

It is much easier *by content* where you can use the [Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to replace a substring by another.

Regex would be an option, but even then it's not pretty:

```
Regex.Replace(str, "^(.).(.)$", "${1}1$2"
```